# Add Variable product into cart automatically when cart total is more than 25

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I want to add automatically one variations product into cart when cart total is become more than 25. The automatically adding variation product price need to set as 0 and also customers cant change the qty or need to disable the Qty filed for free product. I added below code and its working fine only the issue when page reloading or cart updating the the Qty of free product is increasing every time.I only want to sell 1 qty of free product. How to do that ? Code is following below.

```
function aapc_add_product_to_cart() {
    global $woocommerce;

    $cart_total = 25;   
    if ( $woocommerce->cart->total >= $cart_total ) {
        if ( ! is_admin()) {
            $free_product_id = 2696; 
            $variation_id = 2697; 
            $arr = array();
            $arr['Color'] = 'Blue';// Product Id of the free product which will get added to cart
            $found      = false;
            //check if product already in cart
            if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
                foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                    $_product = $values['data'];

                    if ( $_product->get_id() == $free_product_id )
                        $found = true;                  
                }

                // if product not found, add it
                if ( ! $found )

                    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $free_product_id,1,$variation_id,$arr );
            } else {
                // if no products in cart, add it

                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $free_product_id,1,$variation_id,$arr );
            }        
        }
    }        
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'aapc_add_product_to_cart' );
function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    $cart_total           = 25; // If cart total is more than this value.
    $free_product_id    = 2697; // Set price to 0 of this free product.
    $carttotal = 0;
    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
        $_product = $value['data'];
        if ( $_product->get_id() == $free_product_id ){
            continue;
        }
        $carttotal += $value['line_total'];
    }
    if ( $carttotal >= $cart_total ) {
        $custom_price = 0; // This will be your custome price  
        foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
            $_product = $value['data'];
            if ( $_product->get_id() == $free_product_id ){
                $value['data']->set_price( $custom_price );
            }           
        }
    }   
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'hide_quantity_input_field', 20, 2 );
function hide_quantity_input_field( $args, $product ) {
    // Here set your product IDs in the array
    $product_ids = array(2697);


    // Handling product variation
    $the_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_variation_id() : $product->get_id();
//var_dump($the_id);
    // Only on cart page for a specific product category
    if( is_cart() && in_array( $the_id, $product_ids ) ){
        $input_value = $args['input_value'];
        $args['min_value'] = $args['max_value'] = $input_value;
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below code in the `functions.php` and replace with required `product id`

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'allowed_products_variation_in_the_cart', 10, 5 );

    function allowed_products_variation_in_the_cart( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variations) {

    $product_b = 14091;

    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        $cart_product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
        if ($cart_item['variation_id']) {
            $cart_product_id = $cart_item['variation_id'];
        }

        if ( ( $variation_id == $product_b) ) {

            wc_add_notice(__('You can\'t add this product.', 'domain'), 'error');
            $passed = false; // don't add the new product to the cart
            // We stop the loop
            break;
        }
    }

    return $passed;
}
```

Comment: This will not work because when user adding that free product directly in to cart at that time product is price is not 0 and product qty need to change